# What is the largest size an opening can be in a load bearing wall without a beam install

Tags: doors

I have a 20 foot load bearing wall.  How many openings can I have in the wall and how wide can they be?

Comment: Is this a stud wall, or brick/block?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't touch the load bearing elements (the vertical studs) you can make all the holes you want.

Once you need to cut one of the load bearing studs you will need to make sure the load that it carried is properly redistributed.

Comment: You assume a stud wall.  What about brick?

Comment: @MartinBonner all the bricks are load bearing elements...

Comment: ... but removing a single brick in a brick wall is fine, so "don't touch the load bearing elements" is not correct in that case.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not ALL bricks are Load bearing. The ancient Romans learned that in about the 5th or 6th century BC. If the wall is already built, you can remove bricks to create a "corbal" arch.

Comment: In wood frame walls, the key word is "load" bearing. If the load comes from beams spaced 4' apart on the wall, then all the studs between the beams could be removed, if it's not a "shear" wall.

Answer (score 0):

None. It's load bearing. If you remove an element of load bearing, you need to replace it.

Now, technically speaking, chances are highly likely not all the wall elements are load bearing, but without details, we can't say.